# Manually propagate upstream downstream relationship in AWS X-Ray

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-xray

I am building a system that goes something like:

```
                                  /-> Stream to Lambda -> DynamoDB
API Gateway -> AWS Lambda -> DynamoDB
                                  \-> Stream to Lambda -> DynamoDB
```

So an API Gateway call triggers a lambda which saves to DynamoDB. Other lambdas are triggered by that DynamoDB save which do some computation and save new data to dynamodb

I've added AWS X-Ray tracing but AWS X-Ray shows this as three different trees:

- API Gateway to Dynamo
- 'Clients' -> Lamdba -> DynamoDB
- 'Clients' -> Lamdba -> DynamoDB

[image: the service map]

In the image the bottom trace is triggered by API Gateway but the first two are triggered by DynamoDB and then write back to it

If I pass the trace ID manually through DynamoDB to the downstream lambdas is there a way I can tell x-ray that the downstream lambdas are flowing from DynamoDB?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that's possible. Essentially you just have to add an `X-Amzn-Trace-Id`-header  with your persisted trace-id as value.

From the [AWS X-Ray documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/xray/latest/devguide/xray-concepts.html#xray-concepts-tracingheader) (although with a slightly different intention):

> **Tracing Header Security**
>
> A tracing header can originate from the X-Ray SDK, an AWS service, or
>   the client request. Your application can remove `X-Amzn-Trace-Id` from
>   incoming requests to avoid issues caused by users adding trace IDs or
>   sampling decisions to their requests.

How you'd add the header before initializing the X-Ray client depends on the programming language and X-Ray SDK you're using. You should also take into consideration a possibly existing `X-Amzn-Trace-Id`-header, if your Lambda function gets invoked by services which might pass such a header as well.

Comment: So, in Lambda 1 I capture `Root=1-5b4b923f-fd411c0c7bca240fd93caaf3;Parent=19ce7ff41b08e00e;Sampled=1` pass that through DynamoDB and set that in Lambda 2. Lambda 2 doesn't even show that it is writing to dyanmodb now